# breaking out of command loop but exit code not the reason?

Tags: bash, scripting, exit, exit-status

I run the following:

```
echo "while emacs;do echo $?;done;echo Exit code: $?;" | bash
```

If I exit emacs through the menu or the close button, it prints exit code 0 and restarts.

If I exit emacs through typing
(kill-emacs 1)
ctrl-x ctrl-e

Emacs is killed and the loop is killed as well, but the exit code is still 0.

What is causing it to break out of the loop?

UPDATE: As per pqnet's advice I used single quotes instead, the code now reads:

```
echo 'while emacs;do echo Exit code: $?;done;echo "Exit code: $?";echo "Loop End."' | bash
```

This produces the same result.  I assume I need to save the value of the pid within the while loop.  So I try:

```
echo 'while epid=$(emacs);do echo Exit code: $epid;done;echo "Exit code: $epid";echo "Loop End."' | bash
```

If these results are to be trusted then exit code in both cases is an empty string (or invisible binary), but I don't think that's correct either?  Is my asusmption of the 'return value' being an exit code an incorrect one, or just that epid is not capturing it?

UPDATE:
One of the answers explained why I wasn't getting the expected results, but now I am curious to know what code would allow me to view the exit code of emacs, since none of what I've come up with does that.

Comment: You're `echo`-ing the exit code of the `while` loop.

Comment: using double quotes will have `$?` expanded before executing echo or bash. Try escaping the `$` to `\$` or use single quotes

Comment: I made some adjustments to the original post, let me know if you have any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RTFM](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html):

> #### while
>
> The syntax of the `while` command is:
>
> ```
> while test-commands; do consequent-commands; done
> ```
>
> Execute *consequent-commands* as long as *test-commands* has an exit status of zero. The return status is the exit status of the last command executed in *consequent-commands*, or zero if none was executed.

If you want to acquire a return value from *test-commands*, you'll need to assign it to another variable explicitly:

```
#!/bin/bash

while
        emacs
        ret=$?
        ((ret == 0))
do
        echo "Exit code: $ret"
done
echo "Exit code: $ret"
echo "Loop End."
```

Comment: Why would I RTFM when you just helpfully made it so I don't have to?

Comment: @RobF Revised to answer your new question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop evaluates on a boolean value. In this case you could also read it as `while true` or `while 0`. So if `emacs` returns another value like `1` if it is killed the loop ends.

Comment: That part is intended, which is why I print the exit code twice.  Just wanted to know why emacs returned zero in both cases and I think I may have gotten my answer above.